# How to use an existing database file (.db) to an ionic 6 and capacitor

Tags: angular, database, sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am completely new to ionic with angular and i tried a lot of different things to import a .db file to an ionic capacitor with angular
i have used sqlite plugin which only allows you to create a db (i thinked to convert the db file to a sql file and import it like manually)
i tried to use sqlitedbcopy but while running it doesn´t find the .db file but i checked to the xcode project or android project and the file is copied, but strangely it doesn´t find it
i am completely frustrated because i am completely out of new ideas so i am begging right now for help :D hehe, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think *sqlitedbcopy* is having an issue with Capacitor but works perfectly with Cordova.
https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy/issues/69

If it's possible, try to import .sql instead of .db file with *SQLite Porter* https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite-porter

I think you are looking for this. It's possible to copy the .db file with below capacitor module.
https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite